# Yet another Htaccess Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK I thought eveything was hunky-dory until I wanted to shorten a few URL's to which I thought would be a piece of Cake.

I have development my own MVC structure, in which all pages go via the index.php and depending on the url the relative contollers and models get loaded on the fly. This gives me nice and clean url's and makes the application easier to develop as it becomes bigger.

So within my Htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and within my index.php I count the length of the url and load in the needed controller etc...

```
$length = count($url); 

if($length > 5)
        {
            $this->Error->index();
            return FALSE;
        } 

    switch ($length) 
    {
        case 5:
            $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3], $url[4]);
            break;

        case 4:
            $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3]);
            break;

        case 3:

            $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
            break;

        case 2:
            $controller_name->{$url[1]}();
            break;

        default:
            $controller_name->index();
            break;
    }
```

This all works absolutely fine, so here is my problem, I have a url www.thepage.com/accounts/general_users/profile/[account_name]

So I wanted to shorten this url by cutting out the 'accounts/general_users/' I tired the following within my htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^profile/april.lee$     accounts/general_users/profile/april.lee [QSA,L]
```

But this doesn't seem to want to play nice with my initial RewriteRule, if its place below the first RewriteRule it just does not render, if its above it seems to break the application.

Im pretty stumped on what to do, and would love a little bit of guidance/advice. I really would like to come up with a solution and not have to re-work the entire application.

Update to demonstrate how I load my Controller and Model:

1- I get and clean the URL:

```
// Get Clean URL 
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : NULL;
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$url = explode('/', $url);

// Start Session
session_start(); 

// Create Application Core
require_once(APP_PATH . "core/core.php");
$AC = new Application_Core($config);
```

2- Check if it is empty or not

```
if(empty($url[0]))
{
        // Load and Instantiate Model
    require(APP_PATH."models/m_index.php");
    $this->Model = new m_index();

    // Load and Instantiate Controller
    require(APP_PATH."controllers/index.php");
    $controller = new index();
    $controller->index();   
} 

else
{

// Load and Instantiate Model
        $model_file = APP_PATH."models/m_".$url[0].".php";
        if(file_exists($model_file))
        {
            include($model_file);
            $model_name = "m_".$url[0];
            $this->Model = new $model_name();
        }
        else
        {
            echo $url[0];
            $this->Template->render_error($this->error_page, $this->error_message);
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Load and Instantiate Controller
        $controller_file = APP_PATH."controllers/".$url[0].".php";

        if(file_exists($controller_file))
        {
            require(APP_PATH."controllers/".$url[0].".php");
            $controller_name = $url[0];
            $controller_name = new $controller_name();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Template->render_error($this->error_page, $this->error_message);
            return FALSE;
        }

        $length = count($url); 

        // Check Method Exists
        if ($length > 1) {
            if (!method_exists($controller_name, $url[1])) {
                $this->Template->render_error($this->error_page, $this->error_message);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        if($length > 5)
        {
            $this->Error->index();
            return FALSE;
        } 

        switch ($length) 
        {
            case 5:
                $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3], $url[4]);
                break;

            case 4:
                $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2], $url[3]);
                break;

            case 3:

                $controller_name->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
                break;

            case 2:
                $controller_name->{$url[1]}();
                break;

            default:
                $controller_name->index();
                break;


        }
```

3 - Length is checked and the appropriate Controller and Model are loaded in, if the method does not exist the user is redirected to an error page.

Comment: RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ accounts/general_users/profile/$1 [QSA, L]

Comment: Hi @Adam thanks for the comment, but that seemed to bring up the dreaded 500 Internal Server Error Page.

Comment: I added a better explanation of what I meant as an answer.

Comment: @faa this didnt seem to work, it load once, but once refreshed it broke the app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it might be handled better by not controlling via length of the URL. What would happen if someone enters extra variables to the end of the shortest link to see what happens? Would they get behavior from your site that is meant for other users, this could be bad.

You can use the htaccess to do everything your switch is doing with less headache.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [nc]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ accounts/general_users/profile/$1 [QSA, L]
RewriteRule ^url_for_control1/match$ index.php?controller=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

**Edit:**
  To make this work with your index.php file depends on what it does, if your control function redirects the user to another page you can make the htaccess do that for you. 
For example, the following..

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [nc]

RewriteRule ^employees/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?first=$1&last=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Will redirect a request to: 
http://www.mysite.com/employees/john/doe 
to: 
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?first=john&last=doe&anyother=variables_sent 
... using GET or POST variables depending on how the page was requested.
Knowing this you can create cleaner URLs that are search engine friendly and easier to read and understand by humans. You can continue to send requests to the index.php by searching for specific characteristics in the url and telling the index.php page via a variable which control function to use.

It is not a good idea to determine actions for a page based solely on the amount of characters in the URL for many reasons, including making a site that can easily be changed and upgraded.

[Net Tuts has a decent beginners tutorial as well for htaccess.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/)

Comment: Hi Adam, this looks a little confusing as im not too familiar with htaccess, I updated my question to show the inner workings of the index.php file... How would i go about implementing your code above to work with my index.php ... Im a little confused... Cheers Lee